# Read certain paragraph from text files matlab

Tags: matlab, extract, textscan

I am using matlab to extract words from text files. I have several text files and I want to textscan '**AB**' part of each file.

From my knowledge I know how to read specific lines from a text file, however, because I want apply the same code for all the text files in the folder, the line number is going to differ each time and I will have to change it every time.

This is what all of my text files looks like (sample):

> PMID- 27401974
>   OWN - NLM
>   STAT- Publisher
>   DP  - 2016 Jul 8
>   TI  - North-seeking magnetotactic Gammaproteobacteria in the Southern Hemisphere.
>   LID - AEM.01545-16 [pii]
>   AB  - Magnetotactic bacteria (MTB) comprise a phylogenetically diverse group of
>         prokaryotes capable of orienting and navigating along magnetic field lines. Under
>         oxic conditions, MTB in natural environments in the Northern Hemisphere generally
>         display north-seeking (NS) polarity, swimming parallel to the Earth's magnetic
>         field lines, while those in the Southern Hemisphere generally swim antiparallel
>         to magnetic field lines (south-seeking (SS) polarity).
>   CI  - Copyright (c) 2016, American Society for Microbiology. All Rights Reserved.
>   FAU - Leao, Pedro
>   AU  - Leao P

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please see [ask]. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) is your friend:

```
fid = fopen('/path/to/file.txt');
line = fgetl(fid);
target = '';
found_ab = false;
while ischar(line)
    line = strtrim(line); % remove trailing white space
    if ~found_ab        
        res = regexp(line, '^AB\s*-?\s*(\S.*)$', 'tokens', 'once');
        if ~isempty(res)
            target = res{1};
            found_ab = true;
        end
    else
        % we found an "AB -" line, we see if there are multiple lines here
        res = regexp(line, '^[A-Z]+\s-\s'); 
        if ~ismepty(res)
            % we reached the end of AB - lines
            break;
        end
        % there are multiple text lines for "AB - "
        target = [target, line];
    end
    line = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
```